# CUDA function only works for certain elements

Tags: c++, c, memory, cuda

I'm trying to test a feature by writing a very simple CUDA program. The program only adds two vectors and display the result. It has both the CPU and GPU solvers and they should display the same results. The program takes an input as the size of the arrays to generate (like this ./test [numelements]).

Problem with my program is that it works for 3 or less elements. Beyond that, the error appears like this:

```
*** Error in `./test': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001927070 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7fd382a31a46]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0x770a1c)[0x7fd3821b8a1c]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0x770b6f)[0x7fd3821b8b6f]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0x268b7e)[0x7fd381cb0b7e]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0x1b1a10)[0x7fd381bf9a10]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0xe7efd)[0x7fd381b2fefd]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(cuInit+0x43)[0x7fd381b087d3]
./test[0x4214bc]
./test[0x422e31]
./test[0x4439e2]
./test[0x402a27]
./test[0x402955]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fd3829d2ea5]
./test[0x402719]
======= Memory map: ========
```

Here is my entire application:

the main file: test.cpp:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "util.h"
#include "utilCUDA.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);

    double *a, *b, *c, *cBase;
    int j;
    a = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    b = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    c = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));    
    cBase = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));

    srand(time(NULL));
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            a[j] = rand() % 10;
            b[j] = rand() % 10;
        }

    printVec(a,size);
    printVec(b,size);
    add(a,b,cBase,size);
    printVec(cBase,size);

    addCUDA(a,b,c,size);
    printVec(c,size);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    free(cBase);
    return 0;
}
```

util.h and its corresponding util.cpp

```c
#ifndef __UTIL_H__
#define __UTIL_H__


#include <stdio.h>

void add(double *a, double *b, double *c, int size);
void printVec(double *v, int size);
#endif
```

util.cpp:

```c
#include "util.h"

void add(double *a, double *b, double * c, int N)
{
    int tid = 0;
    while (tid < N)
    {
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
        tid += 1;
    }

}

void printVec(double *v, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%f ", v[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

utilCUDA.h:

```c
#ifndef __UTILCUDA_H__
#define __UTILCUDA_H__
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

__global__ void myAdd(double *a, double *b, double *c, int size);

void addCUDA (double *a, double *b, double *c, int size);
#endif
```

utilCUDA.cu:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "utilCUDA.h"

#define THREAD_PER_BLOCK 128

__global__ void myAdd( double *a, double *b, double *c, int size ) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;//blockIdx.x;    // this thread handles the data at its thread id
    if (tid < size)
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
}
void addCUDA(double *a, double *b, double *c, int size)
{
    double *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(double) );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(double) );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(double) ); 

    cudaMemcpy( dev_a, a, size * sizeof(double),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_b, b, size * sizeof(double),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    myAdd<<<(size - 1)/THREAD_PER_BLOCK + 1,THREAD_PER_BLOCK>>>( dev_a, dev_b, dev_c,size );

    cudaMemcpy( c, dev_c, size * sizeof(double),
                  cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    cudaFree( dev_a );
    cudaFree( dev_b );
    cudaFree( dev_c );
}
```

And finally the Makefile:

```c
CC = g++
CUDACC=nvcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

CUDAFLAGS=-c
SRC=test.cpp utilCUDA.cu
OBJ=test.o utilCUDA.o util.o
CUDA_INCLUDE = /usr/local/cuda-5.5/include

all: test

test: $(OBJ)    
    $(CUDACC) $(OBJ) -o test

test.o: test.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test.cpp -I $(CUDA_INCLUDE)

utilCUDA.o: utilCUDA.cu utilCUDA.h
    $(CUDACC) $(CUDAFLAGS) utilCUDA.cu

util.o: util.cpp util.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) util.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o test
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `a = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));`, etc ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm really a newbie ...

Comment: @njuffa do you want to provide that as an answer?  I would upvote. I was able to reproduce the problem.  Then I made that change to 4 lines in `test.cpp`, recompiled, and I was no longer able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates an issue with host-side memory allocation. In particular, the posted code only allocates one `double` element for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `cBase`, although the usage indicates that the allocation of `size` elements was intended. Try changing the code as follows:

```
a = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
b = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
c = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));    
cBase = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
```